# how to write output from rapidminer to a txt file?

Tags: data-mining, text-mining, rapidminer

i am using rapidminer 5.3.I took a small document which contains around three english sentences , tokenized it and filtered it with respect to the length of words.i want to write the output into a different word document.i tried using Write document utility but it is not working,it is simply writing the same original document into the new one.However when i write the output to the console,it gives me the expected answer.Something wrong with the write document utility.
Here is my process

> > READ DOCUMENT --> TOKENIZE  -->  FILTER TOKENS --> WRITE DOCUMENT

Comment: I would advise you to upgrade to the newest version of RapidMiner Studio, we are now at 7.1 (https://rapidminer.com/products/whats-new-rapidminer-7/)
With this, you could use the 'Write CSV' operator for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

`Cut Document` (with `(\S+)` as the regular expression)

Inside the `Cut Document` operator use `Tokenize` with `(non letters)` followed by `Filter Tokens`

Use `Combine Documents` after `Cut Document`

Then use `Write Document`

This should do what you want

Andrew