# Rapidminer : how to named result from loop file

Tags: rapidminer

Sory if its basic question..

My process just like this :

[image: my rpm flow]

how can i save the text file for each file, i use macro but failed. but when i use for add the attribute it's success. i just use rapidminer as my praprocess step. i wanna do other process with other tool i want to use.

extract macro name is "filename" and write as text

Thanks for help..

Comment: solved, i just use %{a} for auto increment number for filename..

Comment: my process READ DOCUMENT --> TOKENIZE --> FILTER TOKENS --> WRITE DOCUMENT, like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23884817/how-to-write-output-from-rapidminer-to-a-txt-file

Comment: Great that you found a solution yourself.